# ExoPlayer Cast extension - Unable to see closed captions on TV

Tags: android, exoplayer

We are using ExoPlayer cast extension. The video files are 'mp4' and has inbuilt English subtitles. We are able to see the closed captions in the device using '**Player**' class and selecting DefaultTrackSelector which has preferred language set as "en". But when we are casting this to TV using '**CastPlayer**', the closed captions are not displayed on a TV, only video plays. We are creating MediaInfo object as below:

```
val movieMetadata = MediaMetadata(MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_MOVIE)
movieMetadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_TITLE, TITLE)      
val mediaInfo = MediaInfo.Builder(videoUrl)
            .setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_BUFFERED)
            .setContentType(getMimeType(Uri.parse(videoUrl), this))
            .setMetadata(movieMetadata).build()
```

Is there any language setting for '**CastPlayer**' too? Any help would be appreciated.